# Get user object using userid in django

Tags: python, django

Hello i am new to django,

i am creating an authentication system using django.

Once a user is logged in i am storing the value in a session.

```
 user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
request.session['mid'] = user.id
```

and when i refresh i can receive the session id

```
uid = request.session['mid']
```

But i am not sure how to get the userdatas from the user id. can any one tell me how can get the user object using the user id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use simple [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) query.

```
try:
    uid = request.session['mid']
    userobj = User.objects.get(id=uid)
except User.DoesNotExist:
   #handle case when user with that id does not exist

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can store the user id in `request.session`, and query the id
with django ORM manually.

But after installing the `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware` middlewares, on a higher level, Django can hook this authentication framework into its system of request objects. I believe most django projects will use the code below to get authenticated user from web requests.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
         user = request.user
```